# getting BAD_ACCESS Error Calling C++ from Objective-C++. All files are .mm but still this issue

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I know this has been asked a lot and I did implemented all I have created by looking around here and there.

I have all objective C files as .mm.

Also I can see in output console that "this = (a *) NULL" so the object used to call b(int x) function is null.

Here is my situation I am initialising c++ class from objective c++(.mm) class.
but I am getting BAD_ACCESS.

"a.cpp"

```
#include "a.h"
void a::b(int x) {
    cout <<"hi";
    c.push_back(x); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here.
    cout<<c.size();
}
```

other files are as follow.

"a.h"

```
#ifndef __Cperiments__File__
#define __Cperiments__File__
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class a {
    public :
    vector<int> c;
    void b(int x);
};
#endif /* defined(__Cperiments__File__) */
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.mm

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
                   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "a.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    a* objA;
}
-(id) init;
@property(readonly,assign) a* objA;
@end
```

ViewController.mm

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

    -(id)init
    {
        if ((self = [super init]))
        {
        objA = new a();
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        objA->b(5);
    } 
    @end
```

What else I am missing so that I can push some ints in vector.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the `init` method is never called.

Comment: c is never initialized, you need to implement constructor for class "a".

Comment: @Krzysztof vectors do not need to be initialized.  They are　initialized directly onto the stack when the object a is created (they have to be, since they are not pointers)

Comment: @borrden i see, well in that case no idea what is wrong with that code.

Comment: @borrrden I am checking on that.thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @borrrden that was  the issue......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @borrrden in comments I never called init in appdelegate.mm.

replaced this line in appdelegate.mm

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

with

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

Thanks for quick help.